# Building ionic/react for android - Invalid project type "react"

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-react

I'm using `@ionic/react` in order to build an Android app. Everything worked fine, but I do not seem to be able to build an android version of it.

The commands

- `$ ionic build`
- `$ ionic serve`
- `$ ionic integrations enable capacitor`
- `$ ionic cap add android`
- `$ ionic cap open android`

all give me the error message:

```
[ERROR] Invalid project type: react (project config: .\ionic.config.json).
    Project type must be one of: angular, ionic-angular, ionic1, custom
```

Do I interpret this correctly that `@ionic/react` is not yet full supported?

I am confused, thought I built an `@ionic/react`-app for android before.

Been following this documentation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/react/your-first-app

My `ionic.config.json`:

```
{
  "name": "Prototype",
  "integrations": {},
  "type": "react"
}
```

Important dependencies from `package.json`:

```
    "dependencies": {
        "@ionic/react": "^4.11.0",
        "@ionic/react-router": "^4.11.0",
        "@react-google-maps/api": "1.7.12",
        "@types/jest": "^24.0.18",
        "@types/node": "^12.7.12",
        "@types/react": "^16.9.5",
        "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.1",
        "@types/react-router": "^5.1.1",
        "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.0",
        "ionic": "4.12.0",
        "ionicons": "^4.6.3",
        "react": "^16.10.2",
        "react-dom": "^16.10.2",
        "react-router": "^5.1.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.1.0",
        "react-scripts": "3.2.0",
        "typescript": "3.6.3"
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same issue, you have to update ionic to the latest version.

```
npm uninstall -g @ionic/cli
npm install -g @ionic/cli@latest
```